# AS3 Randomly load movieclip from library without repeatation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, random

I have a spot a difference game that every time I solve an image, and I click next it will load another MC from library.

Below is my code to randomly loaded the MC from library:

```
var showMcNum:Number = 0;
var movieList:Array = [mc1,mc2,mc3];
function getRandomMovie():MovieClip
{
    return new movieList[Math.floor(Math.random()*movieList.length)];
}
nextBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextClick);
function nextClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var mc:MovieClip = getRandomMovie();
    addChild(mc);
    mc.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
    mc.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
}
```

I would like to every time I click the next button, then it will load another MC from library without repeatation of those MC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want an MC to repeat, just remove it from the list when you return it.

```
function getRandomMovie():MovieClip
{
    var index:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*movieList.length);
    var mcClass:Class = movieList.splice(index,1)[0];
    return new mcClass();
}
```

Here is a version using a second array to allow you to repeat the list  as per TheSHEEEP's comment:

```
function getRandomMovie():MovieClip
{
    if(!movieList.length) {
        movieList = spareList;
        spareList = [];
    }
    var index:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*movieList.length);
    var mcClass:Class = movieList.splice(index,1)[0];
    spareList.push(mcClass);
    return new mcClass();
}
```

**Removing the previous MovieClip**

In order to remove the previous MovieClip, you should keep a record of it outside of your `nextClick` function, so that you can remove it before getting the next one:

```
//declare mc outside
var mc:MovieClip;
function nextClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //remove mc first
    if(mc && mc.parent) removeChild(mc);
    //(optional) free up old mc for garbage collection
    //now replace the contents of mc with a new random instance
    mc = getRandomMovie();
    addChild(mc);
    mc.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
    mc.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
}
```

Of course you may need to do more than just remove the previous mc.  Before you point your `mc` reference at a new object, you should free the other one up for garbage collection by stopping any internal code from executing and removing any listeners.

Comment: In addition to that, if you don't want to lose the MCs altogether, I'd suggest having two lists: One to hold the playable MCs and one to hold the ones already played. So if the first one is empty, you can assign the second one to it and start again.

Comment: @pizza - I've added a version using TheSheep's idea.  Items are being removed from the array fine for me, I just built a test. Are you getting an error?  Or do you mean that the previous mc is still on the stage?

Comment: You have to declare the spareList variable before using it, of course, just like you did with the movieList one. _@shanethehat SHEEEP with 3 E please :D_

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @shanethehat for the answer. But after the last MC is loaded and press the next button again it will prompt an error, it is because there are no more MC to load from library.

I've modify abit of the code so that when all the MC from library are loaded and the button know it and won't have any errors.

```
var showMcNum:Number = 0;
var movieList:Array = [mc1,mc2,mc3];

function getRandomMovie():MovieClip
{
    var index:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * movieList.length);
    var mcClass:Class = movieList.splice(index,1)[0];
    return new mcClass();
}

nextBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextClick);

//declare mc outside;
var mc:MovieClip;
function nextClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (showMcNum < 3)
    {
        //remove mc first
        if (mc && mc.parent)
        {
            removeChild(mc);
        }//(optional) free up old mc for garbage collection
        //now replace the contents of mc with a new random instance
        mc = getRandomMovie();
        addChild(mc);
        mc.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        mc.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        showMcNum++;
    }
    else
    {
        //code what you wanna do here after all the MC is loaded
    }
}

mc = getRandomMovie();
addChild(mc);
mc.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
mc.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
showMcNum++;
```